# Calling python script with config file from node.js as a child process

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I am calling a python script as a child process from node.js, the python script uses a config.ini file for some reason the python script does not call the config file when its called as a child process, but when I launch the python script 'using python script.py' it works, and when a replace the value from the config.ini file with an actual value inside the script.py it works also, how do I fix this?

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import sys
import re
import json
file = 'config.ini'
config = ConfigParser()
config.read(file)

rCARD_NUMBER = r"number:\s(\d+\*+\d+).*?"
regex = rCARD_NUMBER*int(config['atm']['bCARD_NUMBER'])
# re.DOTALL to match any characters including newline
input = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
# print(input.read())
matches = re.findall(regex, input.read(), re.DOTALL)
print(json.dumps(matches))
```

config.ini

```
[atm]
bCARD_NUMBER = 1
```

Here is how I call the python script as a child process from node :

```
 var largeDataSet = [];
    // spawn new child process to call the python script
    // pass the python script the uploaded file as an argument
    const python = spawn("python", [
      "./config/script.py",
      req.file.path,
    ]);

    // collect data from script
    python.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
      console.log("Pipe data from python script ...");
      largeDataSet.push(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to be happening is that `ConfigParser().read(file)` reads based off of the current working directory, which would be where the JavaScript file is, not inside the `config` folder.

You can get around that by using `pathlib` (pre-installed, core library)

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import re
import json
file = 'config.ini'
config = ConfigParser()
config.read((Path(__file__).parent / "config.ini").absolute())

rCARD_NUMBER = r"number:\s(\d+\*+\d+).*?"
regex = rCARD_NUMBER*int(config['atm']['bCARD_NUMBER'])
# re.DOTALL to match any characters including newline
input = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
# print(input.read())
matches = re.findall(regex, input.read(), re.DOTALL)
print(json.dumps(matches))
```

Your JavaScript and `config.ini` file should remain the same.